# How to use submit button present outside the component and also needs validation

Tags: html, css, angular, templates, reactive

I have one form template driven i am handling it using id like #firstname and then using ngModel.so basically i want once the code gets validated it should let the button know to get enabled or diabled which is present outside the component.

Note: i am not using form tag here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please explain how to handle form validation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using form

   If your component has a template variable

   ```
   <form #form="ngForm">
       ...
   </form>`
   ```

   You can get it (and expose as public property of your component)
   using ViewChild

   ```
   @ViewChild('form') form:NgForm
   ```

   Now in your parent, can access to the form if you access to the
   child

   ```
   <app-child #child ></app-child>
   <button (click)="submit(child.form.form)">submit</button>

     submit(form:FormGroup)
     {
       if (form.valid)
         this.result=form.value;
       else
         this.result="Invalid form"
     }
   ```
2. Using simple control

   ```
    <input name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" #nameID="ngModel" required>
   ```

   The ViewChild

   ```
   @ViewChild('nameID') control:FormControl
   ```

   Your parent like

   ```
   <child-control #childControl></child-control>
   <button (click)="submitControl(childControl.control)">submit</button>

     submitControl(control:FormControl)
     {
       if (control.valid)
         this.result=control.value;
       else
         this.result="Invalid control"
     }
   ```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sx4snl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)